# Generate Random 20 Non-repeating numbers in C++

Tags: c++

So I have a program where I generate a 8x8 matrix which are rooms. So we have 64 rooms. Now I have to generate 20 random rooms to be dirty. I'm trying to figure out how I can generate 20 non repeating numbers to use as the dirty rooms. This is my code so far:

```
//generate the 20 random dirty rooms 
int col;
int row;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    col = ranNumber();
    row = ranNumber();
    cout << "\t" << col << "  " << row << endl;

    if (room[row][col] == 'D')
    {
        cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
        col = ranNumber();
        row = ranNumber();
        cout << "New number " << row << col << endl;
        room[row][col] = 'D';

    }
    else

        //set the room as dirty 
        room[row][col] = 'D';
}
```

*ranNumber():

```
int ranNumber() {
   return rand() % 8;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not dealing with a particularly large data set, I'd suggest using `std::shuffle`.  You'll want to initialize your rooms with 20 dirty (the positions don't matter, so do whatever is easiest), then let `std::shuffle` rearrange the rooms.  This avoids you having to write your own loop in case you get poor luck with your random generator, and better expresses your intent.

Sample code:

```
int main() {
    char rooms[8][8];
    for(auto i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        for(auto j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            rooms[i][j] = (i == 0) ? 'D' : ' ';
        }
    }
    printRooms(rooms);
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::default_random_engine re{rd()};
    auto b = (char *) rooms;
    std::shuffle(b, b + (8 * 8), re);
    std::cout << "----------------------\n";
    printRooms(rooms);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit: `rooms[i][j] = (i * 8 + j < 20) ? 'D' : ' ';`

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of room numbers (0-63) and use as a picking basket. Whenever a room has been picked, you swap that room out of the selectable range.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // fill_n
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>   // iota
#include <random>    // mt19937, random_device, uniform_int_distribution

int main() {
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}()); 
    char room[8][8];
    constexpr int room_count = 8 * 8;
    std::fill_n(&room[0][0], room_count, '.'); // fill rooms with an initial value.

    char numbers[room_count];
    std::iota(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), 0); // 0 - 63

    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
        int last_selectable_room = room_count - i;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, last_selectable_room);
        auto& selected = numbers[dist(prng)];
        *(&room[0][0] + selected) = 'D';
        // swap the selected room number with the last selecable room number
        // to make sure that the selected room can't be selected again
        std::swap(selected, numbers[last_selectable_room]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nN73cO)

This is likely going to be 2.3 - 2.4 times faster than the `std::shuffle` approach if you use `g++` or `clang++`. [Benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/ywbS8y2hh4avl0a9ksxk3rh-qTQ)

Comment: I like the approach, but the "faster" based on cpu/noop time may be a little misleading.... Now if it were an 8000x8000 array -- then a timing comparison may be more insightful `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, the good thing about this is that it seems to scale better than the shuffle approach, For an 800x800 array, it's [~2.9 times faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/efp7fEHejH9ZHDTzCK_yJR8xgPE) for example. It requires a little more temporary memory though. At 2000x2000 it seems to go down again and is only [~2.2 times faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/hS5NglZzMbveZI1wiu0AwGnfRRk) Of course, these examples have an error in the room number (since a `char` can't hold that many room numbers :-) )

Comment: That more like it. Hard to know with an 8x8, but twice as fast on a 2kx2k is saying something.

Answer (score 0):

If selecting the dirty rooms uniformly at random is truly important, you could build a random permutation of the rooms using [Knuth's shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (be careful, it is easy to blunder!) and picking e.g. the first 20 ones of the result as dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `std::shuffle()` and a single-dimension array, exploiting the fact that an m x n matrix can be represented as an array containing m*n elements

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

class random_room_generator {
public:
    random_room_generator(const size_t matrixRows, const size_t matrixColumns) :
        m_matrixRows(matrixRows),
        m_randomRoomList(),
        m_nextRoom(0)
    {
        // Create a list of all the room numbers.
        const size_t totalRooms = matrixRows * matrixColumns;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < totalRooms; ++i) {
            m_randomRoomList.push_back(i);
        }

        // Shuffle the list.
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 g(rd());
        std::shuffle(m_randomRoomList.begin(), m_randomRoomList.end(), g);
    }

    std::pair<size_t, size_t> next() {
        // Get the room number:
        const size_t roomNumber = m_randomRoomList[m_nextRoom++];

        if (m_nextRoom == m_randomRoomList.size()) {
            // Loop back round to the start if we get to the end of the shuffled list.
            m_nextRoom = 0;
        }

        // Convert the room number into a row and column using the modulus/division operators:
        return std::pair<size_t, size_t>(roomNumber % m_matrixRows, roomNumber / m_matrixRows);
    }

private:
    size_t m_matrixRows;
    std::vector<size_t> m_randomRoomList;
    size_t m_nextRoom;
};
```

Then, in your function, instead of calling `ranNumber()`, you can use an instance of `random_room_generator` to save a list of random rooms and then get 20 rooms from that list:

```
random_room_generator gen(8, 8);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> roomCoords = gen.next();
    const size_t row = roomCoords.first;
    const size_t col = roomCoords.second;
    
    cout << "\t" << col << "  " << row << endl;

    //set the room as dirty 
    room[row][col] = 'D';
}
```

You can find a working example here: https://godbolt.org/z/xKLmjm